# How to disable `abbrev-mode`?

Tags: spacemacs, minor-mode, abbrev

I am using Spacemacs and it always ask me to save `.cache/abbrev_defs` which is very annoying.

I tried to put `(abbrev-mode -1)` in `dotspacemacs/user-config` function. But it still ask for save the abbrev_defs file.

Comment: You can keep abbrev mode on and get no save requests with `(setq save-abbrevs 'silently)`

Answer (score 2):

You disable `abbrev-mode` the same way you disable any minor mode.

Interactively:

`M-- abbrev-mode`

From Lisp:

`(abbrev-mode -1)`

`C-h f abbrev-mode` tells you:

> **`abbrev-mode`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `abbrev.el`.
>
> `(abbrev-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle Abbrev mode in the current buffer.
>
> With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable Abbrev mode if `ARG` is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
>   Abbrev mode if `ARG` is omitted or `nil`.
>
> In Abbrev mode, inserting an abbreviation causes it to expand and
>   be replaced by its expansion.